# Wrong area51 proposal link on answers.onstartups.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, hyperlinks, site-proposal

Area51 proposal link on [answers.onstartups.com](http://answers.onstartups.com/) link to [answers.stackexchange.com](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/lookup/answers.stackexchange.com) and "Oops! Something Bad Happended!" error occurs

[image]

I am not sure this is specific to answers.onstartups.com, so I am posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build - there was a mismatch in names for the onstartups proposal.

Comment: @You nope - thanks for pointing that out